scipy.signal.resample vs Ramer Douglas Peucker

The graph data is loaded from a wave file and only 1600 samples are used. For resampling, I have used
resampled_audio_data = scipy.signal.resample(audio_data, len(audio_data) // 10)

Here is the code for calculating RDP
def rdp(points, epsilon):
    """
    Implementation of the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm.
    
    Parameters:
    points (array): Array of data points.
    epsilon (float): Tolerance parameter to control the reduction level.
    
    Returns:
    reduced_points (array): Array of reduced data points.
    """
    if len(points) < 3:
        return points
    dmax = 0
    index = 0
    end = len(points) - 1
    for i in range(1, end):
        d = perpendicular_distance(points[i], points[0], points[end])
        if d > dmax:
            index = i
            dmax = d
    if dmax > epsilon:
        rec_results1 = rdp(points[:index+1], epsilon)
        rec_results2 = rdp(points[index:], epsilon)
        results = np.vstack((rec_results1[:-1], rec_results2))
    else:
        results = np.array([points[0], points[end]])
    return results

def perpendicular_distance(point, start, end):
    """
    Calculate the perpendicular distance of a point from a line.
    
    Parameters:
    point (array): The point.
    start (array): The start point of the line.
    end (array): The end point of the line.
    
    Returns:
    dist (float): The perpendicular distance.
    """
    if np.array_equal(start, end):
        return np.linalg.norm(point - start)
    return np.abs(np.linalg.norm(np.cross(end - start, start - point))) / np.linalg.norm(end - start)

And to calculate RDP from 160 points of resampled_audio_data
time_data = range(0, len(resampled_audio_data))
reduced_points = rdp(np.column_stack((time_data, resampled_audio_data)), 0.00001)

Although the number of points produced by RDP is either the same or a bit less than resampling, you can see in the image that the results are almost identical. The resampling code is based on fft yet both are producing the same result. Performance-wise sampling is much faster than RDP. I was under the impression that scipy must be using some c/c++ based optimized code but it's based on pure Python, even fft is based on Python used in resampling. The result:
Resampled in =  0.0 secs  Points =  160
RDP in =  0.06255841255187988 secs  Points =  160

Question: What is so special about RDP?
Question: Is it possible to improve the RDP code further for performance?
Please suggest if there are any other algorithms can produce the same results and performance-wise better than these two.
Cheers

"Although the number of points produced by RDP is either the same or a bit less than resampling, you can see in the image that the results are almost identical." You seem to be using a really small epsilon value. The smallest visible change on that graph has a magnitude of 0.01. By setting epsilon to 0.00001, it's a hundred times more selective in dropping points than that.

"I was under the impression that scipy must be using some c/c++ based optimized code but it's based on pure Python, even fft is based on Python used in resampling." SciPy's fft implementation uses PocketFFT internally, which is written in C. Link to this part of the code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/2ecac3e596fdb458c85000e7707a8f5f46926621/scipy/fft/_pocketfft

"Please suggest if there are any other algorithms can produce the same results and performance-wise better than these two." I would point out that if RDP is not dropping any points, you could replace it with an algorithm that does nothing, which runs in 0 ms. :) Presumably that's not an acceptable solution to you, but I don't know why. What's the ultimate goal?
